# passing another function as dot operator in js like A.mainFunction(parm1,parm2,parm3)

Tags: javascript

I have a function A which let say perform addition,

```
function A(a,b){
return a+b;
}
```

now I need to create another function which calls the function A after some time as follows.

`A.callFunction(1000,1,2)` //where 1000 is the time interval after which A needs to be called and 1,2 are the values which will be passed in A function.

How can I achieve this? And what is its significance.

Therefore, callFunction would be a function that enables ANY function (A) to be called after some specified duration, like the above mentioned format.

Comment: A would then have to be an object or a class.

Comment: @Kevin.a it's neither an object nor class. I am adding some additional details in the question.

Comment: Something like this? `A.callFunction = function(delay, ...params) {
  setTimeout(_ => this(...params), delay)
}` Update: If you want it for any function, you need to add it to `Function.prototype`

Comment: @adiga can you provide a code snippet for Function.prototype? Like `B.callFunction` can perform some another action.

Comment: @christo-pher18 `Function.prototype.callFunction = function(delay, ...params){ // same function as above }`

Comment: @adiga Cool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved using [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) (for recurring needs)

**Example**

```
function A(a,b){
  alert(a+b);
}

setTimeout(function() { A(1, 2) }, 3000);
setInterval(function() { A(1, 2) }, 3000); //for recurring needs
```

the second parameter is in ms so 3000ms means 3s

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

- Adding a new property to the function prototype to apply to *all* functions, and
- Using the spread operator (`...`) to dynamically pass in all parameters from the deferred function to the originnal.
- Using `setTimeout` to defer the execution of the function

This is an example using `Promise`:

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(delay, ...args) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(this(...args));
  }, delay));
}

function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b){
  return a - b;
}

console.log('add immediate', add(1, 2));
add.defer(1000, 3, 4)
  .then(result => console.log('add delayed', result));

console.log('subtract immediate', subtract(2, 1));
subtract.defer(1000, 6, 4)
  .then(result => console.log('subtract delayed', result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main function is like bellow

```js
function A(param1, param2) {
  console.log("I am executed");
  return param1 + param2;
}
```

The calling function is like bellow

```js
function CallMe(timeInterval, param1, param2, callBackFunction) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callBackFunction(param1, param2);
  }, timeInterval);
}
```

Call it anywhere like this

```
CallMe(10000, 1, 2, A);
```

at first, it will go to the `CallMe()` function for `setTimeout()` it will wait what the time interval you will pass to the function

Comment: you can use the spread operator and args. Because now he is limited to 2 params.

Comment: I don't have to pass the A function in the params. But should be accessed with the dot opeator like A.CallMe(10000,1,2)

Comment: @christo-pher18 thats just not possible, because A is a function not an object. Also there is no built in method that allows you to do this in Javascript.

Comment: I tried to make it as it shows in the questions. So that it should not confuse. But yes, you are right.

Comment: @Kevin.a Thankyou.

Comment: @christo-pher18 There are many ways to do it, But the best way should be to pass the callback and the value you need. On the large scale you might get undefined when you will access it with the dot operator.

Comment: This was something which I already did, but  I had some restrictions in calling the function so ended up using `Function.proptype.callback = function(delay,...parms){setTimeout(_=> this(..params),delay)} ` and then calling it `A.callback(1000,1,2)`.